# Angular Cypress.io test with Google Login popup window

Tags: angular, cypress, angular-test

Is it possible to login to a Google account with Cypress.io using the Google authentication pop-up window?

I can get the window to open, but then Cypress can't detect the ID for the email input field.

The error is: "CypressError: Timed out retrying: Expected to find element: '#identifierId', but never found it."

```
it('Login', function() {
    cy.visit('home')
    cy.get('#signin-button').click()
    cy.get('#google-login-button').click()
    // cy.wait(1500) // wait doesn't help
    cy.get('#identifierId')
    .type('user@gmail.com') // <<-- error here
  })
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This does not work due to Cypress not having fully implemented [iframe support](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/136).

However, Cypress does not suggest visiting 3rd party applications within your tests. There are many reasons for this including:

- It is incredibly time consuming and slows down your tests.
- The 3rd party site may have changed or updated its content.
- The 3rd party site may be having issues outside of your control.
- The 3rd party site may detect you are testing via a script and block you.
- The 3rd party site may be running A/B campaigns.

Cypress has outlined the downsides to visiting 3rd party sites you do not control and some workarounds in their docs. [I suggest reading the full explanation here.](https://on.cypress.io/best-practices#Visiting-external-sites)

Comment: Thanks for the details. I’m really surprised. I’m not visiting any third-party sites. My own application uses Google Authentication so the Google pop-up is part of my app. Maybe it’s just semantics, but since Google auth is part of my site I don’t consider it third-party for Cypress testing.

Comment: Yes, by third-party we mean that your authentication service relies on another parties application code. If Google was down or your internet was not working while running your application locally, your application would not work. This is a good way of identifying whether you use what Cypress calls a '3rd party site'.

Comment: OK, but with all due respect, my project is a SaaS application that uses public 3rd-party APIs for its fundamental features. I can't adhere to a rule that says 'don't use any 3rd-party API' or 'don't rely on Internet access.' Without Internet, my application literally can't function.

Comment: Sorry if I misspoke. I was not saying that you should not *use* 3rd party APIs, just that there are many downsides to testing a 3rd party applications functionality end-to-end and it is often advisable to have most tests test that your application is communicating properly with the 3rd party API.

Answer (score -3):

check if the DOM element is visible. identifierId is not visible