# Why stub in cypress may not work for route called after page was loaded

Tags: cypress

I am using cypress to write tests and have a problem which doesn't appear in every test. In some cases it works and I don't know why. So...

**The Problem:**

I defined a route and alias for it in beforeEach:

```
beforeEach(function () {
  cy.server()
  cy.route('GET', '/favourites?funcName=columnPreset', []).as('columnPresetEmpty')
  cy.visit('#/search')
})
```

Stub works fine if http request occured on page load. 
But if I perform request responding to click event (modal dialog opens and executes http request) it just appear in commands not makred as stubbed and following `cy.wait('@columnPresetEmpty')` fails with request timeout.

```
 it('does not work', function () {
   cy.get('[data-test=button-gridSettings]').click()
   cy.wait('@columnPresetEmpty')
 })
```

At the same time in other tests I have almost similar functionality where request is performed just by clicking on a button, without opening new modal window. It's the only difference.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The problem sounds similar to this question [Angular Cypress.io test with Google Login popup window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47805037/angular-cypress-io-test-with-google-login-popup-window), although the discussion degenerates into one about 3rd party sites, essentially I see it as the popup window is outside of Cypress' view.

Comment: If you have influence over the way the app opens the window (and depending on how it is opened) you may be able to add a reference to the child window on your main window (for example see [MDN Window.open()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open)) and work from there. Are you able to show the code that opens the window?

Comment: Ok, it's a modal - that should be testable.

Comment: @RichardMatsen, thank you for a response. Sorry, I don't know why I wrote 'New window'. It's totally confusing. It's just a modal dialog. No windows or iframes.

Comment: Let me review my modal tests and I'll post something. First thing that comes to mind, modals often open with an animation which delays the view render. A simple `cy.wait()` might do it.

Comment: @RichardMatsen, should be, I understand it. And checked a number of times route and tried various approaches. Just weird. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the reason causing such behavior. Problem was not in a modal window itself, but code performing second request was called in promise's callback of another request. Something like:

```
fetch('/initData')
  .then(loadView)
```

And loadView function executed second fetch.

So when I removed loadView from promise's callback both requests become visible for cypress.

Answer (score 4):

The issue might be cypress can not yet fully handle `fetch` calls. You can disable it the following way but make sure you have fetch polyfill. This will then issue XHR requests which cypress can observe.

```
cy.visit('#/search', {
    onBeforeLoad: (win) => {
        win.fetch = null
    }
})
```

More to read here:
https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/95#issuecomment-281273126

Comment: Thanks for thought, I know about it and use this approach for all tests.

Comment: I slightly updated my question so not to confuse anyone with 'fetch'.

Comment: How would you delete the fetch call when there is no visit happening but the fetch call is either a webhook or an event. For example we have a form page where new users type in their email. Once the email is typed in and the user has clicked on the next field in the form a fetch call is made to check if the email is already in use. How do I mock that? I cannot do cy.visit. What is the alternative?

Answer (score 0):

For info, I tried it out on my search modal (in a Vue app) and it works ok.

What I did:

- created a dummy file named **test-get-in-modal.txt** in the app's static folder
- added an `http.get('test-get-in-modal.txt')` inside the modal code, so it only runs after the modal is open
- in the spec, did a `cy.server()`, `cy.route('GET', 'test-get-in-modal.txt', []).as('testGetInModal')` in a `before()`
- in the `it()` added `cy.wait('@testGetInModal')` which succeeded
- changed to `cy.route('GET', 'not-the-file-you-are-looking-for.txt'...`, which failed as expected

---

The only difference I can see is that I `cy.visit()` the page prior to `cy.server()`, which is not the documented pattern but seems to be ok in this scenario.

Comment: Thanks for an answer. I still can't make it work. Already tried different combinations. Nothing helps at all. :(